# Visual C# - Rendering images from form?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a fun application written in Visual Studio (C#), and I'm wondering - What I do is I draw panels in certain ways on the form - if it's possible to render the form, without taking a screenshot?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "taking a screenshot" you mean "sending <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>", then there's a better way, using [`System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yfzc507.aspx):

```
using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height)) {
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) {
        g.CopyFromScreen(this.PointToClient(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, this.ClientSize);
    }

    // Your form is now rendered into b.
}
```

If you want to include the border, just use `Size` instead of `ClientSize`, and `this.Location` instead of `this.PointToClient(Point.Empty)`.

Alternatively, you can use `this.DrawToBitmap`:

```
using(Bitmap b = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height)) {
    this.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));

    // Your form is now rendered into b.
}
```

This will work even if your form doesn't have focus. However, it will draw the border and it will draw it in Windows Basic style if Aero is active.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible to capture the visual of the form as an image other than what is offered by some sort of screenshotting library (if that's what you're asking).